# html5 audio mp3 files less than 4 seconds long will not play()

Tags: javascript, html, audio, mp3

I am using html5 audio to playback mp3 files on a educational platform with localised dialects for children to complete web based tasks (mini games).

I am using some JavaScript to do this

```
window.audioFile = new Audio("/assets/tasks/1/sounds/FM_Practice_1.mp3").play();
```

to playback files dynamically and it works perfectly albeit if the mp3 files is less than 4 seconds long, it will not playback I've noticed upon inspection.  This is the only difference between the mp3 files, all have the same frequency, codec etc.

Can anyone assist me why this is the case, I assume it may be a buffering issue.  Will I need to make the clips longer than 4 seconds?

Edit: I am using chrome to test, I assume it is standardised however.

Answer (score 0):

i don't think its an issue with the duration of sound check this code below. it plays a sound that is less than 4 secs.

```
audio = new Audio("http://soundjax.com/reddo/54324%5EBEEP2.mp3");
audio.play();
```

i have tested it on chrome. i guess there may be some problem in you mp3 file

Comment: the file in question plays back perfectly using a normal media player ?

Comment: the answer turned out to be the bit rate of the mp3 file. The audio tag is quite sensitive about this. Anything above 128kbps it will not play. A lot of encoders automatically choose the highest quality bit rate (usually around 320kbps like your media player is doing) and the audio tag won't play them. Check them (audio properties will tell you fairly easily) and re-try them. Strangely, OGG doesn't seem to suffer from the same problem, but better safe than sorry.

Comment: Hi, it seems to work now, I don't recall changing anything.  Agreed it seems to be sensitive.